# how to enumerate multiple arrays using same base name

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to create multiple arrays holding random lists of file names referencing the number of elements in another array. How can I append a $cntr var (beginning with cntr=0) to the end of the new array names so they are directly referenced with elements in other array?

Wow I hope that reads somewhat sensible. Here is what I got going on so far that I hope helps make better sense of what I mean:

```
function fGenRanList() {
    cntr=0
    while [[ "$cntr" -lt "${#mTypeAr[@]}" ]] ; do
        n="${nAr[$cntr]}" ; echo "\$n: $n"
            tracks${cntr}=() ; echo "\$tracks${cntr}: $tracks${cntr}"
        while ((n > 0)) && IFS= read -rd $'\0' ; do
            tracks${cntr}+=("$REPLY")
            ((n--))
        done < <(sort -zuR <(find "${dirAr[$cntr]}" -type f \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' \) -print0)) 
        ((cntr++))
    done
}
```

error I get is:

```
/home/user/bin/ranSong_multDirs.sh: line 95: syntax error near unexpected token `"$REPLY"'
/home/user/bin/ranSong_multDirs.sh: line 95: `                       tracks${cntr}+=("$REPLY")'
```

But I first commentted out the echo statements from the tracks${cntr}=() array initialization to get rid of a similar error, but unsure whether or not track${cntr} gets initialized in the first place.

By the end I should end up with as many track(n) arrays as there are elements in ${#mTypeAr[@]}, using the numeric var stored in array ${nAr[$cntr]} to determine how many elements each track array will contain.

Maybe I am making things more difficult than need be, trying to implement arrays into older scripts I have both in order to make them a little more efficient, but I guess am driven primarily to get a better handle on using BASH arrays to store vars for similar but multiple processes which I seem to do often in my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line, which is not valid `bash` syntax,

```
tracks${cntr}+=("$REPLY")
```

to

```
declare "tracks${cntr}+=($REPLY)"
```

Rather than having a syntactic assignment, the `declare` command takes a string that *look*s like an assignment as an argument; that argument is processed by the shell first, so if `cntr` is currently 3 and `$REPLY` is `foo`, the actual assignment performed is

```
tracks3+=(foo)
```

The `declare` command gives you a level of indirection in making parameter assignments.

Comment: how do I access the elements in the array? When I try to echo "${tracks$cntr[0]}" for example I get "bad substitution error

Comment: btw I have had the need for such a solution several times in the past, so if this can work and I can understand how then I can see using this again... unless there is a way in bash to create arrays of arrays

Comment: The syntax for indirect expansion of an array element is a bit strange. For a normal variable, you would simply do something like `foo=5; bar=foo; echo ${!bar}`. For arrays, you have to consider the index as part of the variable name. `var="tracks$ctr[0]"; echo ${!var}`.